# Create Windows 8 User From Linux Environment

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-8, user-profiles

I have a dual boot laptop with Win8 + Ubuntu installed on 2 separate partitions. Yesterday, as a result of a series of tweaking and things I shouldn't have been doing, I'm facing the evil `user profile service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded` error on Win8, hence being unable to login to my windows system.
Having Ubuntu as my guardian angel, I think creating a new user from the Linux system would be the easiest method to solve this problem. Any ideas on how to do this?
**Notes (The question ends here, this is just extra notes for clarifying the situation and reasoning my solution):**
1. I'm aware of this thread: [Create a Windows XP user from a linux partition](https://superuser.com/questions/286685/create-a-windows-xp-user-from-a-linux-partition)
But the solution posted for this one included changing the password, but what I'm facing won't get fixed by changing the password.
2. [This solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/user-profile-service-service-failed-the-logon-user/4ed66b21-c23e-42f1-98b2-706dcf931fae) includes a way to fix it through registry. However, running "regedit" using wine from Ubuntu, I checked the "Profilelist" key in registry. Noticed that there are no sub-keys at all. Either they were deleted, or they don't exist in Windows 8 (which is unlikely); which again, leads to my current solution: "Creating an entirely new user".
3. My windows 8 currently only loads into safe mode (sicne windows 8 doesn't provide the good old F8 escape key), and I used "chntpw" to enable the Administrator account, to which I still failed to login and received the same User Profile error.
4. net.exe encounters some serious errors while being run through wine.

Comment: This not the error where it says "Temporary profile will be created"? Because thatb one usually resolves itself (just shut down and reboot).

Comment: No. I rebooted several times and nothing changes.

Answer (score 6):

If you can load to the log in screen, use Linux to rename the c:/windows/system32/sethc.exe file to c:/windows/system32/sethc2.exe, then rename cmd.exe to c:/windows/system32/sethc.exe.

when you get to the log on screen, press shift 5 times to engage stickykeys. instead of a sticky keys window, you'll get an administrator command prompt. from that, you can use the net user  "" command to set up a new user account.

Comment: That's actually a pretty clever workaround, but you probably want to COPY cmd, rather than just changing it outright.

Comment: Agreed - this is a beautiful workaround... it works perfectly on Windows 7, 8, and 10.  And yes... copy the cmd rather than renaming it is a very good idea.

Comment: Can I use Narrator.exe if sticky keys are disabled?